# ¿Como mantener datos en mi sesion durante todas las peticiones en Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session, sesiones

Saludos, lo que necesito es mantener unos datos que envió desde un formulario en un array que almaceno en Session de laravel, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

En la routes.php tengo:

```js
Route::bind('evento', function($slug){
    return Deportes\Evento::where('slug', $slug)->first();
});



Route::get('tienda/agregar/{evento}', [
    'as' => 'inscribir-evento',
    'uses' => 'TiendaController@agregar']);


Route::get('tienda/{slug}', [ 
    'as' => 'eventos-detalles',
    'uses' => 'TiendaController@detalle']);


Route::post('tienda/inscribir/{evento}',[
       'as'=> 'inscrito-inscribir',
       'uses'=>'TiendaController@inscribir'
    ]);
Route::get('tienda/', 'TiendaController@index');
```

En mi Controller:

```js
public function index()
    {
       // $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
        dd(\Session::get('tienda'));
       // return view('tienda.tienda', compact('tienda'));
    }

public function agregar(Evento $evento){
       
        $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
        if ($tienda = null) {
            $tienda[$evento->slug] = $evento;
            \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
            return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
        }
        else{
                 
            \Session::forget('tienda');
             $tienda[$evento->slug] = $evento;
            \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
            return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
        }
        
        

    }
    
    public function inscribir(Evento $evento, Request $request){
        $tienda = \Session::get('tienda');
        $inscrito = [            
            'nombre'=>$request->get('nombre'),            
            'edad'=>$request->get('edad'),
            'cedula'=>$request->get('cedula'),
            ];
        $tienda[$inscrito['cedula']] = $inscrito;
        \Session::put('tienda', $tienda);
        dd(\Session::get('tienda'));
        //return view('tienda.inscribir', compact('tienda'));
    
        
    }
```

Ahora, cuando inscribo a la persona en el evento, me agrega a la persona por su cedula al array pero cuando voy a ver si se mantiene en el array en otro lado, no me aparece la persona...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho lo que necesito es agregar varios inscritos al evento... el evento ya esta en base de datos, pero los inscritos quiero tenerlos temporalmente durante toda la sesión, hasta que se cumpla las condiciones como se podría hacer?

Comment: En teoría esa es la forma correcta, a mí me funciona sin ningún inconveniente. ¿Algún otro dato que deberíamos saber de tu proyecto? Versión de php, o cómo almacenas las sesiones, etc...

Comment: Saludos Shaz, gracias por responder, pues si funciona bien, solo que no se mantiene los datos que envio desde un formulario, el que si se mantiene es el dato de Evento, que esta ya en la base de datos, pero el segundo array que es un numero de cedula(num de identificacion venezolano)  proviene de un formulario y cuando lo envio lo toma inmediatamente, pero cuando pruebo para verlo y hacer un dd en otra peticion, no lo guarda, y como ves estoy actualizando la sesion con los datos correctamente... no entiendo por que no me mantiene esos datos... Agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar!

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que en algún punto estás sobreescribiendo la sesión (el valor de tienda), ¿tal vez estás entrando al formulario de nuevo?

Comment: No creo, porque despues que le hago llamado el metodo  `inscribir()` me guarda y muestra los datos actualizado, luego inmediatamente abro otra pestaña y me voy a usar el metodo `index()` donde solo quiero obtener, con `Session::get` el array para probar y no me mantiene los datos desde el formulario... Me parece extraño...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, realmente hice una prueba y la sesión funciona sin problema, lo que ocurre es que estás usando el helper `dd()` y no estás permitiendo que la modificación de la sesión se almacene realmente, lo cual ocurre al final del ciclo de vida de Laravel.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Quita el `dd()` y prueba con `dump()` en la siguiente vista que muestres.
- Utiliza `Session::save()` después de `Session::put()` para almacenar los datos de la sesión de inmediato, aunque esto sería en casos específicos o para probar.

Comment: Excelente @Shaz probare ambas dos y seguire haciendo pruebas. Primera pregunta que hago en esta plataforma y me llama mucho la atencion, estare investigando y ayudando si puedo. Saludos!